# Different path for two users added in Docker group

Tags: linux, docker

My laptop OS is Ubuntu 20.04, and I have these users:

```
saeed (my main user)
test1 (created for testing only)
```

I have added all of them to `docker` group and they all can run docker commands, but I see two different behaviors. I explain with example:

1. I run `docker run -d --name saeed nginx` with `saeed` user. Then I `docker inspect container_name` and I see this is the `overlay2` (and other files) path:

```
/home/saeed/.local/share/docker/...
```

1. I run `docker run -d --name test1 nginx` with `test1` user. Then I `docker inspect container_name` and I see this is the `overlay2` (and other files) path:

```
/var/lib/docker/...
```

Why is there the difference? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your saeed account is configured to run docker in the [rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/) configuration. That means you're talking to a separate docker daemon running as your user, storing files in your users home directory. There's no need to add your user to the `docker` group for this, and doing so would defeat the security gained by running a rootless daemon (since that same user could reconfigure their `DOCKER_HOST` variable to talk to the daemon running as root, escalating their privileges).

The test1 user is using the traditional docker install running a single daemon as root. You'll likely see better performance and fewer issues doing this, but ensure that you trust the user running commands as the root user on the host.